# BlackJack Winning condition

Tags: c#, winforms

I need some help with a small problem. When I win or lose two conditions are met and a message box appears twice. Making one win or lose count as two wins or losses in my scoreboard. This sometimes happen and other times works correctly.
I have tried putting in an endpoint, I tried using if for all of them and I tried using else if, is there another way for the game to check for only one condition?

```
public void Scoring(int playerscore, int dealerscore) //scores the dealer and  player scores
    {
        //string winGame = "verloor";

        //while (winGame != "Wenner")
        //{ 
            if (dealerscore > 16) //check if dealer score is greater than 16
            {
                if (dealerscore < playerscore && playerscore > 21) //win lose conditions
                {
                    L++; //add one lost to scoreboard
                    tLose.Text = L.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("Dealer Wins!!", "Lost!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
           //         winGame = "Wenner";
                    goto Einde; //if condition is met go to end marker
                }

                else if (dealerscore > playerscore && dealerscore < 22) //win lose condition
                {
                    L++;
                    tLose.Text = L.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("Dealer Wins!!", "Lost!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
             //       winGame = "Wenner";
                    goto Einde;
                }

                else if (dealerscore == playerscore && playerscore < 22) // draw condition
                {
                    D++; //add one draw to scoreboard
                    tDraw.Text = D.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("It's a tie!!", "Draw!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
               //     winGame = "Wenner";
                    goto Einde;
                }

                else if (dealerscore > 21 && playerscore > 21) //win lose condition
                {
                    L++;
                    tLose.Text = L.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("Dealer Wins!!", "Lost!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                 //   winGame = "Wenner"; 
                    goto Einde;
                }

                else if (playerscore > 21) //lose condition
                {
                    L++;
                    tLose.Text = L.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("Dealer Wins!!", "Lost!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                   // winGame = "Wenner"; 
                    goto Einde;
                }

                else if (dealerscore < playerscore && playerscore < 22) //win lose condition
                {
                    W++; //add win to scoreboard
                    tWin.Text = W.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("You Win!!", "Winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    //winGame = "Wenner"; 
                    goto Einde;
                }

                else if (dealerscore == playerscore && dealerscore > 21) //win los condition
                {
                    L++;
                    tLose.Text = L.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("Dealer Wins!!", "Lost!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    //winGame = "Wenner"; 
                    goto Einde;
                }

                else if (dealerscore > 21 && playerscore < 22) //win lose condition
                {
                    W++;
                    tWin.Text = W.ToString();

                    MessageBox.Show("You Win!!", "Winner!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    //winGame = "Wenner"; 
                    goto Einde;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }

            }
        Einde:; //end marker
```

Comment: Start by rewriting it without the `goto` statements, they make it harder than it needs to be to follow the control flow. Then separate your display logic from your scoring logic. You'll work it out!

Comment: Easiest fix is that those goto become return statements, then you never hit anything x2

Comment: Is there any chance this function is being called twice? It looks OK to me. I'd try putting a breakpoint at the start and seeing what happens, and checking the call stack when it is called.

Comment: Yes, and run it through the debugger. Step through it to work out where that second message box is being triggered.

Comment: Use `break;` if you are running this through a loop. And anyway if you use `else if` cannot hit twice. As @briantyler says debug and check whether method calls twice.